# Query is not considering condition in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I am trying execute below script everything is working fine but it is not considering condition in where clause (`@inputfield is not null`).

Please help me to fix this

```
Declare @inputfield as varchar(100)
Declare @fields as cursor

create table #Temptable (inputfields varchar(200))
insert into #Temptable values ('streetAddress')
insert into #Temptable values ('zipcode')

set @fields= cursor for Select * from #temptable

Open @fields 
fetch next from @fields into @inputfield

While (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)

Begin
            insert into temptableoutput
            Select @inputfield ,count(Distinct objectId) as Entitiescount
            from temptable1
            where @inputfield is not null


Fetch next from @fields into @inputfield

End

Close @fields
deallocate @fields
```

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: Maybe it more logically correct to first check if the variable is null? `IF(@inputfield IS NOT NULL ....`

Comment: I am trying to count no of rows in temptable1 for each field where @inputfield is not null.

Comment: because it is not finding that field. try this:- From temptable1, @inputfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dynamic query to build your sql statement

```
Declare @inputfield as varchar(100)
Declare @fields as cursor
Declare @sql as nvarchar(500)

create table #Temptable (inputfields varchar(200))
insert into #Temptable values ('streetAddress')
insert into #Temptable values ('zipcode')

set @fields= cursor for Select * from #temptable

Open @fields 
fetch next from @fields into @inputfield

While (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)

Begin
            set @sql = 'insert into temptableoutput ' +
                        'Select ' + @inputfield + ' ,count(Distinct objectId) as Entitiescount ' +
                        'from temptable1 where ' + @inputfield + ' is not null'

            exec sp_executesql @sql

Fetch next from @fields into @inputfield

End

Close @fields
deallocate @fields
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing details. when I execute above script it is throwing below error.

Comment: Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: Declare @sql as nvarchar then :)

Comment: (1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: I got above error message along with query output but i dont see data in temptableoutput table.

Comment: How have you declared the @statement?

Comment: Declare @inputfield as nvarchar(500)

Comment: I'm glad to help.